# Error on Mustache.render using pre-parsed templates

Tags: javascript, partial, mustache

I get the error `Object [object Array] has no method 'search'` in mustache.js line 103.

I've created an object of templates when the page is ready:

```
window.templates = {};
$("script[type='text/mustache']").each(function(){
    window.templates[this.id] = Mustache.parse(this.innerHTML);
});
```

I then have a json object from my server, the relevant part of which I'm passing into a rendering function.

```
var render = function(data){
    var content = "";
    for (n in data){
        content += Mustache.render(window.templates[n], data[n], window.templates);
    }
    return content;
}
```

I'm attempting to match up templates with models: the `window.template` keys matching the keys in my data object returned from my model. Since templates may contain other templates as partials, I'm passing the entire templates object back in at the end. I can confirm that I'm getting the model name I expect, and that it does properly match with a template.

I'm new to Mustache, so this is probably a simple fix. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your templates? Also please mention version of Mustache you are using (it seems it's not the latest and greatest).

Comment: @twil I'll work on getting them up here but they're pretty basic. And it's whatever the latest version is unless they put up a new one since last Saturday.

Comment: Also please note this works just fine if I don't pre-parse the templates.

Answer (score 1):

Without Mustache version I can only guess but it seems you are using version 0.7.3. If so then you are looking at wrong documentation  (["Pre-parsing and Caching Templates" in master branch](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#pre-parsing-and-caching-templates)). And what you should be looking is ["Compiled Templates" in docs for v0.7.3](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/tree/0.7.3#compiled-templates).

So what you should be doing is

```
window.templates = {};
$("script[type='text/mustache']").each(function() {
    window.templates[this.id] = Mustache.compilePartial(this.id, this.innerHTML);
});
```

and your `render()` function

```
function render(data) {
    var content = "";
    for(var n in data) {
        // don't pass partials. internal cache will be used
        content += window.templates[n](data[n]);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LAI2zHnUpMP8GPrdCiSO?p=preview) to play with.